# encryption / decryption using dictionaries

Tags: python, encryption, dictionary

We were given an assignment to help us understand how python works vs JAVA (more specifically how python dictionaries work).

Our teacher wants us to create a program using non linear dictionaries, example:

```
a = c
b = d
c = e
d = f
e = g
f = h
g = i
```

once we have accomplished this we are supposed to call this program to read a random (already specified txt file) and import the results into "encrypted_" followed by the txt file name, so if we encrypted text1.txt it would be encrypted_text1

This seems all hunky dory, but this lab has baffled me and I was hoping some more experienced python programers here could direct me at some examples of encryption using dictionaries so I could better understand how they work.

Thank You

Comment: Look up the string.translate function, it does what you are required to do.

Comment: I see, is it possible to use that function when calling other text documents you wish to encode?

Comment: Yep exactly. The syntax between python2.7 and 3 is slightly different but in 3 you do: `tab = str.maketrans("123","abc")` to make the translate table. Then `str.translate("1423",tab)` will output `a4bc`.

Comment: Alright so one final question, I tried using that string.translate function and I've got this so far (as a test): <br/>'#!/usr/bin/python

from string import maketrans   # Required to call maketrans function.

intab = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
outtab = "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

str = "this is string example....wow!!!";
print str.translate(trantab);'

how would I go about using this base program to call another text file? I know I'd have to remove the str = and print str.tran part, but I'm not sure what exactly I would need to add

Comment: Ill post an example as an answer gimme 2 secs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example program to translate a text file (note this is python3, if you are using python2.7 you will have to make some changes):

```
from string import maketrans

intab = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
outtab = "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

inputfile = open("your_file_here.txt","r")
s = inputfile.read()

translation = s.translate(trantab)

print(translation)
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using 2.7 probably why it gave me  File "./test.py", line 7, in     <module>
    trantab = str.maketrans(intab, outtab)
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans' only thing I changed (at that time) was your_file to simple.txt, but I get the idea Ill tinker around with it

Comment: @Daniel Like I said, the syntax is different between 3 and 2.7. I said I posted code that works in 3. I edited my code to one that should work on 2.7 but I don't have 2.7 installed to check.

Comment: I saw, that's why I said I was gonna mess with it, just got it working actually, I need to add a few more components but this answered the encryption part. Thank You!